# Multimedia links in big text fields tridion 2013

Tags: 2013, multimedia

I am building website in Tridion 2013 with DD4T and wanted all my multimedia tcm id's in the multi line text field(non rich text) resolved. Does tridion resolves tcm id in text field like rich text?

Comment: Question is not clear. Please add some more information.

Comment: I have a Code component which has a big text field(but not rich text) where I have the html with tcm id's of the binaries instead of hardcoded path. Will these tcm id's get resolved into published path like it does in case of rich text.

Comment: My suspicion is no, but it really depends on the syntax of your link and how you're dealing with it in your template. If you use "regular" link syntax like dwt and the resolve links TBB, it might actually work.

Comment: I'll simply try <a href="tcm:xx-xxxx"> and use the Default Finish Action along with DD4T tbbs. If this doesn't work then will add the type="Binary" or "Multimedia" and see if it works.

Comment: It's not getting resolved, seeing tcm id in the source of the page. Added DFA and also included type. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

In SDL Tridion, creating links towards downloadable Binaries (Multimedia Components) in a Rich Text Field of a component, generates a ComponentLink instead of a BinaryLink on the presentation server. These multimedia components being rarely inserted directly on a Page, the ComponentLink does not get resolved on the front end, and your link will not appear on your page.
Check this - https://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/process-download-links.aspx

Comment: Multimedia component links in rich text are getting resolved. What I have is a big text(non rich text) field having tcm ids of the MM comps and those are not getting resolved. Trying to find a reason on how tridion processes these two fields.